# How to let the type checker know a change in the function definition?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses

### Introduction

I am working on a [python package](https://github.com/karthikrangasai/anton) that lets one create python `dataclass`-es from `YAML` and `JSON` files.
The idea is to reduce boilerplate and provide runtime type-checking of the values in the files to the types defined in the `dataclass`.

Below I show a code example of how everything works and where the issue occurs.

### Code Example

The decorator implementation

```py
def yaml_conf(
    cls=None,
    /,
    *,
    conf_path: str,
    init: bool = True,
    repr: bool = True,
    eq: bool = True,
    order: bool = False,
    unsafe_hash: bool = False,
    frozen: bool = False,
):
    def wrap(cls):
        return yaml_conf_wrapper(
            cls, conf_path=conf_path, init=init, repr=repr, eq=eq, order=order, unsafe_hash=unsafe_hash, frozen=frozen
        )

    if cls is None:
        return wrap

    return wrap(cls)
```

#### The inner wrapper

###### Implementation : 1

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

def yaml_conf_wrapper(
    cls,
    /,
    *,
    conf_path: str,
    init: bool = True,
    repr: bool = True,
    eq: bool = True,
    order: bool = False,
    unsafe_hash: bool = False,
    frozen: bool = False,
):
    dataclass_cls = dataclass(cls, init=init, repr=repr, eq=eq, order=order, unsafe_hash=unsafe_hash, frozen=frozen)  # type: ignore
    actual_init = getattr(dataclass_cls, "__init__")
    setattr(dataclass_cls, "__init_setter__", actual_init)

    def modified_init(self) -> None:
        print(f"Pasring from '{conf_path}', type-checking, and generating arguments.")
        pos_args, kw_args = (1, 2, 3), dict(x=1, y=2)
        getattr(self, "__init_setter__")(*pos_args, **kw_args)

    setattr(dataclass_cls, "__init__", modified_init)

    return dataclass_cls
```

###### Outputs

Running as python code:

```bash
>>> @yaml_conf(conf_path="dummy.yaml")
>>> class Example:
>>>     a: int
>>>     b: int
>>>     c: int
>>>     x: int
>>>     y: int
>>> 
>>> obj = Example()
>>> print(obj)
Pasring from 'dummy.yaml', type-checking, and generating arguments.
Example(a=1, b=2, c=3, x=1, y=2)
```

Running mypy:

```bash
$ mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

###### Implementation : 2

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

def yaml_conf_wrapper(
    cls,
    /,
    *,
    conf_path: str,
    init: bool = True,
    repr: bool = True,
    eq: bool = True,
    order: bool = False,
    unsafe_hash: bool = False,
    frozen: bool = False,
):
    dataclass_cls = dataclass(cls, init=init, repr=repr, eq=eq, order=order, unsafe_hash=unsafe_hash, frozen=frozen)  # type: ignore
    actual_init = getattr(dataclass_cls, "__init__")
    setattr(dataclass_cls, "__init_setter__", actual_init)

    def modified_init(self, any_path: str = conf_path) -> None:  # CHANGE: Addition of the new argument `any_path`
        print(f"Pasring from '{any_path}', type-checking, and generating arguments.")
        pos_args, kw_args = (1, 2, 3), dict(x=1, y=2)
        getattr(self, "__init_setter__")(*pos_args, **kw_args)

    setattr(dataclass_cls, "__init__", modified_init)

    return dataclass_cls
```

###### Outputs

Running as python code:

```bash
>>> @yaml_conf(conf_path="dummy.yaml")
>>> class Example:
>>>     a: int
>>>     b: int
>>>     c: int
>>>     x: int
>>>     y: int
>>> 
>>> print("Scenario 1")
>>> obj = Example()
>>> print(obj)
Scenario 1
Pasring from 'dummy.yaml', type-checking, and generating arguments.
Example(a=1, b=2, c=3, x=1, y=2)
>>> 
>>> print("Scenario 2")
>>> obj = Example("dummy2.yaml")  # New functionality that is desired and also works
>>> print(obj)
Scenario 2
Pasring from 'dummy2.yaml', type-checking, and generating arguments.
Example(a=1, b=2, c=3, x=1, y=2)
```

Running mypy:

```bash
$ mypy test.py
test.py:67: error: Too many arguments for "Example"  [call-arg]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

#### Doubts and Question

- This minor change by adding the argument to the `modified_init` inner function seems to bring in the functionality I desire.
- But I also expected the python type checker to learn that a new argument has been added to that `modified_init` function and hence not throw an type error when I try to pass in new file paths.
- Before the recent change, the type checker (by some luck) knows that there are no arguments required. (It must have asked for 5 arguments `a,b,c,x,y` namely. But it did not.)
- How do I solve the `mypy` issue and let the type checker know that it has to expect one argument ?

Comment: Images of code and links to code are not helpful. The relevant code should be part of the question and since the "magic" is happening in your class decorator, the essential part is missing here. Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what the actual problem is. For example, the entire parsing and validation stuff is completely irrelevant to the question, as far as I can see.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I have updated the question now. Hope it helps.

Comment: Now I see the issue. You have to understand that **dynamically** getting and setting attributes will _always by definition_ be opaque to any **static** type checker. A type checker does not execute your code, it just reads it. The fact that `dataclass` dynamic `__init__` method works at all is just possible because of a special plugin for Mypy. You _could_ hack something together using what was introduced in [PEP 681](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681), but I have my doubts about that additional optional argument for the path.

Comment: `conf_path` is set at the same time as class creation, implying that you can just use standard dataclasses and set `conf_path` as a `typing.ClassVar` instead.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Thanks for pointing me to PEP 681. I will take a look at it to get something working.

Comment: @dROOOze Could you explain why you chose to make `conf_path` a `typing.ClassVar`.
Also, do you want me to pass the `conf_path` here -> `dataclass_cls = dataclass(cls, init=init, repr=repr, eq=eq, order=order, unsafe_hash=unsafe_hash, frozen=frozen)  # type: ignore` ?
Through the `cls` argument ?

Comment: "provide runtime type-checking " <- that is your problem, type-checking in Python is static, prior to  "runtime". Just don't run the static type checker if your runtime code won't match what is in the source files.

Comment: @jsbueno by "provide runtime type-checking" I meant that when you mention an attribute in a dataclass as, for example, `List[str]` then the code ensures the what is being read from the YAML file is a `List` type and that the elements in the list are of `str` type.

This is to partly to avoid using a `Dict[str, Any]` type that `pyyaml` library's `load` functions return. Working with them - without type hints is slightly painful. I am trying to solve this minor problem.